# ASP.NET Boilerplate WebApi methods

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, boilerplate

I'm trying to get to work my project on ASP.NET Boilerplate.

I'm right now creating Dynamic Web API and here is what I have:

My AppService:

```
public interface IBorrowLendAppService : IApplicationService
{
    GetBorrowLendsOutput GetBorrowLends(GetBorrowLendsInput input);
}
```

My Input:

```
public class GetBorrowLendsInput : IInputDto
{
    public byte ItemType { get; set; }
    public int PersonId { get; set; }
}
```

And here's my problem:

- How to invoke this method?
- How can I create GET/POST methods (there's no info about it in Boilerplate docs)

When I'm invoking a method [GET]GetBorrowLends without any data I'm receiving error:

```
{
    "result": null,
    "success": false,
    "error": {
        "code": 0,
        "message": "Your request is not valid!",
        "details": null,
        "validationErrors": [
            {
                "message": "input is null!",
                "members": [
                    "input"
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    "unAuthorizedRequest": false
}
```

When I'm trying to invoke it like:

> .../GetBorrowLends?ItemType=0&PersonId=1

I'm receiving same error

Invoking [POST] with data:

```
{
  "input":{
            "ItemType":"0",
            "PersonId":"1" 
          }
}
```

Returning another error:

```
{
    "result": null,
    "success": false,
    "error": {
        "code": 0,
        "message": "An internal error occured during your request!",
        "details": null,
        "validationErrors": null
    },
    "unAuthorizedRequest": false
}
```

How do I handle that? And how to create GET/POST methods manually?

Thanks

**Edit:**

I have handled problem with not working endpoint. I have wrongly set 'Content-Type' parameter in POST message.

But question about GET/POST methods in ApplicationService is still open.

Comment: Looks like you need to make sure your Routes are defined correctly.

Comment: It seems that they are. Executing different route gives an error that it's not known route

Comment: Could you post your controller code for the method you expect to invoke with your requests? You should probably also include the routing.

Comment: I have handled problem with request which was not working. It was "Content-Type" parameter in POST. My tool set it as 'text' and should be 'application/json'. 

But I have still question about POST/GET methods

Answer (score 2):

The default HttpVerb is set to Post.

```
/// <summary>
/// Default HTTP verb if not set.
/// </summary>
private const HttpVerb DefaultVerb = HttpVerb.Post;
```

Then there is a method in `IApiControllerActionBuilder` to change the verb of an action.

```
IApiControllerActionBuilder<T> WithVerb(HttpVerb verb);
```

You should be able to change the verb with the following call (in `Initialize` of your WebAPI module)

```
DynamicApiControllerBuilder
    .For<ITaskAppService>("tasksystem/taskService")
    .ForMethod("SomeMethod").WithVerb(HttpVerb.Get)
    .Build();
```

Further information could be obtained [on the website](http://aspnetboilerplate.com/Pages/Documents/Dynamic-Web-API).